# Adjustment of sigmoidal growth curves in R

Tags: r

I am trying to adjust a curve of accumulation of nutrients and dry matter of corn in R. I know that the curve that describes is sigmoidal and that the accumulation of dry matter or nutrients depends on time. My first question is how to adjust and graph this in R and then, having several curves of different treatments, as I compare the curves between them. I pass something of what I wrote in R and some data in a link:

```
dataT1 <- subset(C, Trat == "T1")
dataT3 <- subset(C, Trat == "T3")
dataT7 <- subset(C, Trat == "T7")

plotPoints(MS ~ Dia, data = dataT1)

MST1 <- nls(MS ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (Dia - d)))), data = dataT1, start = list(a = min(MS), 
                                                                   b = max(Dia), c = 1, d = round(median(MS))), trace = TRUE)
```

When writing this I miss the error `Error in typeof(x) : objeto 'MS' no encontrado`

Database: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxt2t6sfs52ilq3/database_dudas.xlsx?dl=0

Tks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell nls where to find the object `MS` and also the object `Dia`.
And you need to switch the starting values a bit and use the "port" algorithm in nls:

```
tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
download.file(url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxt2t6sfs52ilq3/Database_dudas.xlsx?dl=1", destfile = tmp)
C <- readWorksheetFromFile(file = tmp, sheet = "Hoja1")

dataT1 <- subset(C, Trat == "T1")
dataT3 <- subset(C, Trat == "T3")
dataT7 <- subset(C, Trat == "T7")

MST1 <- nls(MS ~ a + ((b - a)/(1 + exp(-c * (Dia - d)))),
  data = dataT1,
  start = list(a = min(dataT1$MS),
               b = max(dataT1$MS),
               c = 1, d = median(dataT1$Dia)),
  trace = TRUE, algorithm = "port")

library(nlstools)
overview(MST1)
plotfit(MST1, smooth = TRUE)
```

That gives a fit

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you very much !!! Do you know how I can get the r squared of this equation?

Comment: How about `summary(MST1)`

Comment: And please consider accepting my answer if it fits your request